# Dojo and RequireJS : Error: defineAlreadyDefined(…) when using both on a site

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, amd

I've attempting to create a custom embeddable widget that my users can include on their website.

We provide the code and then add it to their site and then they get access to a bunch of custom widgets that we've produced from our SaaS.

This works great if the site they are trying to embed the widget on DOES NOT already use requirejs, however, when it already uses requirejs, we get the dreaded...

`Error: defineAlreadyDefined(…)` error in console.

What we're doing is as follows:

### Code We Provide Them

They would have instructions to add something like this to their site:

```
    var foobar_load = function(){
        require([ 
          "foobar/rental!53891", 
          "widget/PriceAvailabilityCalculator" ,
          "foobar/widget!/property/53891",

        ], function( Bridge, PriceAvailabilityCalculator, Availability){

            new  PriceAvailabilityCalculator({}).place("widget-container-1");          

            Availability.place("widget-container-2");
        });
    };

    (function() {
        var d = document,
            h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            s = d.createElement('script');

        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'https://www.example.com/v1/sdk.js';
        h.appendChild(s);
    } )();
</script>
```

This would then load our "sdk" code which is just a wrapper of the general bootstrapping process that you would need to do to include dojo on your site.

## Loader Code

So it looks like this:

```
dojoConfig = {     
    async: true,      
    parseOnLoad: false,
    locale: 'en-gb',
    selectorEngine: 'css3',
    paths: {         
        't'         : '//dev.foobar.com/utils/i18n',
        'my'        : '//dev.foobar.com/js/custom/my',
        'foobar'    : '//dev.foobar.com/js/sdk',
        'widget'    : '//dev.foobar.com/js/custom/my/frontend'
    },
    packages: [              
        { name: 'currency', location: '//dev.foobar.com/currency' },
        { name: 'x-application', location: '//dev.foobar.com/x-application' }
    ]
};    

(function() {
    var d = document,
        h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = d.createElement('script');

    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    // If foobar_load is missing.. what should happen?

    s.onload= function(){ 
        require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!", 'x-application'], 
            function(ready, x,r){                                        
            ready(0,  foobar_load );            
        });
    };

    s.src = '//dev.foobar.com/js/dojo/1_9_7/dojo/dojo.js?load';
    h.appendChild(s);
} )();
```

Now, I'm not sure what would be the things we need to do in order to make sure that we can use this custom code on a website which also uses RequireJS.

Comment: what did you try so far ? do you provide built javascript or raw javascript ?

Comment: For this version that I'm doing it's raw unbuilt. But once I"m in production it will be built. As for what I've tried.. I will provide an answer to my question.. since I have a solution, but it's really hacky.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around and getting some advice on #dojo IRC, this is the solution that I'm working with.

It's not a very clean solution but it works. **If you have a cleaner solution, please do post your idea.**. I'm leaving this here to help other people with the same issue.

The idea is to switch out the `require` and `define` functions and then switch them back AFTER dojo.js has finished loading. (A cleaner solution would be to not load dojo.js at all).

It looks like this:

## First

```
    if(typeof define !== "undefined" && typeof require !== "undefined"){
        window.__define = window.define;
        window.__require = window.require;
        window.define = undefined;
        window.require = undefined;
    }
```

## Then after dojo.js loaded

```
 if( typeof window.__define !== "undefined" ) {
        window.define = window.__define;
        window.require = window.__require;
        window.__define = undefined;
        window.__require = undefined;
 }
```